# Problems Booting Windows 8 with Grub 2 HELP ASAP

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows, partitioning

please help. I'm new to linux, decided to try out ubuntu. created a new partition, and replaced windows 8 boot manager with grub 2 by installing grub on the windows 8 partition

now windows doesn't want to start and neither does the recovery environment. I can't mount that windows 8 partition within ubuntu, either because there's a hibernation file, even though I shut down windows 8. It appears to be a new feature :/
your help will be very much appreciated
have a nice day ;)

in grub, there is a windows 8 entry, 2 memtest entries, (don't know what that's for) an ubuntu entry, and ubuntu with advanced options

ok, now I am able now to mount the windows 8 partition in ubuntu ..weird -anyway the reason why windows 8 isn't starting I think, is because I installed grub on the windows 8 partition so now when I click on windows 8, it returns me to grub

is there a way for me to get back the windows 8 boot manager, and dual boot both os'es, or at least get windows 8 starting up in grub?

here's a boot info summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1496147/

here's a new boot info summary after trying to repair the windows 8 bootloader
I reinstalled grub afterwards, because I just get a black screen with a white dash flashing at the top left corner. Now, while on grub that only happens when I try to boot into windows 8
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1496572/

now, I just accidentally deleted the ubuntu partition, but I restored the master boot record before. I tried refreshing windows 8 and nothing happened

GAH!!! I GIVE UP! IF I FORMAT MY ENTIRE HARD DRIVE AND REINSTALL WINDOWS FROM SCRATCH, THAT BETTER WORK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

here's what I did from the command prompt in the windows 8 cd
Diskpart (This built-in utility will help repartition and format the new drive)
List disk (This command will list all the drives present on your system. Note down the drive number of your USB drive)
Select disk # (Replace the # with the drive number that represents your USB drive in the list)
Clean (This command will wipe the entire partition table of the USB drive)
Create partition primary (This command will create a primary partition on the USB drive)
Select partition 1 (This command will select the primary partition for the rest of the process)
Format fs=ntfs quick (This command will quick format the primary partition in NTFS file format) 
Assign (This command will assign a drive letter to the new partition for Windows to work on)
Active (This command will make the partition active to enable booting)
Exit (Closes the DISKPART utility)
then I installed windows 8
it works now.
man, grub caused me a lot of greif...

Comment: Windows 8 doesn't really shutdown in the normal sense. It does a sort of hibernation to speed up boot times and such. Is there an entry in Grub for Win8? If so, what exactly happens when you try to boot it?

Comment: there is a windows 8 entry, 2 memtest entries, (don't know what that's for) an ubuntu entry, and ubuntu with advanced options

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system for help with side-by-side Ubuntu install on computers that came with Windows 8 preinstalled.

Comment: wait I am able now to mount the windows 8 partition in ubuntu
..weird
anyway the reason why windows 8 isn't starting I think, is because I installed grub on the windows 8 partition
so now when I click on windows 8, it returns me to grub

Comment: If would be  like wonderful if you make a **question** instead of all.. that.. text that you put up there, so please **edit** it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Fix the bootsector of your sda1 partition this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix
2. use a Windows disc this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader until you get direct access to Windows
3. then run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s `Recommended Repair` to recover your GRUB menu

Comment: I tried that, and now grub won't load
I only get a black screen, ad a flashing white dash at the top left corner

Comment: as of now, I reinstalled grub, and only when I try to boot into windows 8,  I get that screen
here's a new boot info summary http://paste.ubuntu.com/1496572/

Comment: ok then your Windows boot is deeply damaged. I edited my previous answer.

Comment: I just backed up everything with a live cd, then formatted my hard drive and reinstalled windows