# Trying to boot from Windows CD goes to GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I am trying to boot from disk using the Windows Installation CD, and I always get the GRUB menu. Here is the [boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7455175/). Is there any other information you would need? Booting from a [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) disk or an Ubuntu disk works fine.

I usually select boot from the DVD drive using <kbd>F12</kbd>, and I've also changed settings in the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS), but I only get the GRUB screen, the same as if I was booting from the hard drive.

Also, some background information on Windows issues: Windows crashed and trying to boot in safe mode or normal mode simply restarted the computer. From the GRUB menu the Windows recover option brings me to a stock wallpaper and a mouse I can't move before shutting down. I recently deleted a Windows partition, but the problem existed before this. What would happen if I deleted other Windows partitions?

I do seem to be having trouble with the disk in another computer.

It was simply the disk. I was able to install Windows Vista, but I installed Ubuntu over it as I've come to enjoy the OS.

Comment: A bad disk can waste hours of good troubleshooting.  This is a major reason that people verify a file or disk's checksum - to make sure a copy is proper. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum for more information.

Comment: How to boot from a cd is dependent on your bios, and is unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome aboard! Don't worry about the disk, that happens much more often than I thought it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have damaged the Master Boot Record (which is what Windows uses, while Linux  typically uses a `/boot` partition).

Windows is easy to damage if not shut down properly (such as a power outage). It might also be worth running a physical disk utility to check HD integrity.

If your CD/DVD drive boots other disks and can read the contents of your rescue disk - then I don't suspect that your drive is bad. But perhaps the rescue disk wasn't properly created (will it boot on someone else's Win8 machine)?

Lastly, resizing a windows partition can get tricky. But deleting a Windows partition is a sure way to break the OS.  It may be much easier to purchase a second internal HD, and have each OS segregated for [dual-boot](/questions/tagged/dual-boot), but it is by no means required.  Read through the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=326&s=2f7641c22b79eea651cedfbc33ffd715) and there are a few people who have had similar issues before you.

Comment: I really like this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/236230/89515

Comment: the MBR is 512 Bytes in size. the boot partition would not ever fit there. (that is only 64 ASCII characters!! --english royalty couldn't fit their names there!). The MBR is used by grub to start the chainloading process.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to boot a Windows CD, then you should change the boot device order in the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS). It has nothing to do with the [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) boot-repair. If it's not booting then it's a problem with your Windows CD or the system hardware.

To change the boot device order in your BIOS, you should press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or some function key based on your system at the beginning of the boot process.

Comment: I did do that, so I'm guessing it's a hardware issue. My computer did crash a while back and I've only been running Ubuntu since. Any idea why I would be able to run Ubuntu fine and not Windows?

Comment: Is you CD/DVD drive working fine

Comment: If you CD/DVD drive is working fine then its problem with the windows installation disk. If it comes to installing windows to a separate partition Ubuntu has nothing to do with that. There may be some mistake you are doing while installing windows.

Comment: I believe so, It runs any other disk fine and I can view the files of the windows recovery disk.

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can boot from USB. I'm not sure if the disk is the problem though. Windows did crash a while ago and any windows option from GRUB doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Windows CD/DVD is bootable.

Check your BIOS screen to get into the Boot Menu (<kbd>F8</kbd> for example for some boards). Press the identified key while the motherboard splash shows up.

You should see at least 3 to 4 options like boot from HDD, boot from CD, etc.
Highlight boot from CD and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If the above doesn't get you into the Windows installation screen, check the DVD in any other computer. I doubt the CD is not bootable.

Comment: It was not clear to me what your last sentence was supposed to mean. Please re-edit if my change altered your intended meaning with my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting the windows CD/DVD on some other computer and see if it boots as it looks like the CD/DVD was not burnt correctly.

Also see if you can boot into Windows install wizard using a USB Drive. Use USB install media creator such as [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to do so.